# Access Denied in ajax load (Grails)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, gsp

I want load into div "example_id" file "status.gsp".

But application have access denied to file "status.gsp"

```
$('#example_id').load('status.gsp').hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Comment: what is the complete urls for the page and the ajax resource?

Comment: check if it blocks only script call. like [scriptmethod] in ASP.NET

Comment: for test I put all files in the same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not load the GSP directly (the views directory is not visible by default). Route it via controller's action and use that as URL to load the GSP rendered HTML.

**Example**:

Have a controller named `StatusController` with an action named `status`, which will render the GSP back to the output stream.

```
class StatusController {
  ...
  def status() {
    render(view: "status");
  }
  ...
}
```